# Input impedance of lossless transmission line

Tags: transmission-line

I'm having trouble understanding the following formulas (highlighted) and their corresponding solutions.

I first added up the impedance of transmission lines and found \$Z_{in}\$, but it seems to be wrong. Any explanation will be appreciated.

[image: Formulas with highlighting]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll try to help. Firstly, consider this: the line on the right side has a load of Zl and a length 3(Wavelength)/4. So you get the value of  tan(βl1)=tan(3π2)→∞,  Now, consider the formula given. Taking out  tan(βl) term as common from both the numerator and denominator, you get the equation as

$$Z_{(l)}= Z_o{(Z_lcot(bl)+jZ_o)/(Z_ocot(bl)+jZ_l)}$$

Now note that as tan goes to infinity, cot goes to zero...
Hence, Z(l) results in (Zo)^2/Zl.
Hence , you can now find Z(l). Further, this Z(l) acts as the load for the second transmission line(l2). Similarly, you get the required answer.

Answer (score 1):

The 2nd line (\$Z_{01}\$) is terminated with a mismatched load. So a reflection will be generated there.

The transition from the first line (\$Z_{02}\$) to the second line will also generate a reflection (as well as reflect some of the first reflection back toward the load).

These two reflections will return to the reference plane shown in the diagram.

If you find the total reflected signal returning to the reference plane, then you can determine the equivalent termination that might be placed at that location that would have the same effect as the two line segments plus the load device. That equivalent termination is what we call the input impedance at the reference plane.

Comment: can you help me understand the equations?

Comment: Were you given a formula for transforming an impedance as you move back along the feed line? Use that to find the equivalent input impedance at the L2 to L1 transition. Then find the net reflection there. Then transform again back along the line to the reference plane. As you do that you'll see how your work corresponds to the given solution.

Comment: We are only given one formula for only one transmission line. it is first one in the solution, what I don't know how they came up with the one that is Zin= z_01^2/ZL ! ?

Comment: @user65652 it tells you right in the question. \$\tan\left(\beta l_1\right) = \tan\left(\frac{3\pi}{2}\right) \to \infty\$, so basically \$Z_l+jZ_o\tan\left(\beta l_1\right) \approx jZ_o\tan\left(\beta l_1\right)\$ and  \$Z_o+jZ_l\tan\left(\beta l_1\right) \approx jZ_l\tan\left(\beta l_1\right)\$